# SEO issue with redirecting users to a mobile site

Tags: html, redirect, seo

Will using the following code, give me some SEO problems? My Google rank dropped when I started using it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;document.location" />
</head>
<body>
<p></p>
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<p><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /></p>
<title></title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "http://mobilesite";
}

else{ 
       document.location.href = "http://desktopsite"
}
// ]]></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Stick to one please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413329/whats-going-wrong-seo-google

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to learn HTML structuring first and foremost.

The favicon include and title should always be in the `<head>` containment.

Not sure why you have an XML declaration in their either.

You might as well use the HTML5 doctype as well `<!doctype html>`.

**Regarding the SEO issue**. Content is king. Search engines mainly go on content contained within the page. Now I'm not sure how your JS will affect this as the spiders and robots that crawl the page don't run JavaScript (I could be wrong, hopefully someone will correct me if that's the case).

Comment: Hi thx, I'm new to html and this is some code I found. Could you pls help me out and point me in the right direction to making it more search engine friendly.

Comment: So if they can't process my JS, is it possible to redirect users in html?

Comment: No HTML is for markup only. If the difference between your mobile and desktop site is purely styling you could lookup CSS media queries. If the site is completely different though you will require a redirect mechanism.

Comment: The site is completely different, so using CSS would be a bit crazy. Is PHP or ASP more optimized?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to tell the window width with either PHP or ASP unless you passed it with JavaScript. But you can detect mobiles I imagine by checking the browser agent (might not always be reliable).

Comment: Could I add some keywords or something to let the search engine know it leads to my site?